# Mongoose POST method

Tags: post

I am building a MERN app where I want to use a POST method to send data to my collection in MONGODB.
I imported schema as Messages

here is the code

```
app.post("/messages/new",(req,res) => {
    const dbMessage = req.body;
    
    Messages.create(dbMessage,(err,data) => [
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        else{
            res.status(201).send(data);
        }
    });
});
```

The above way is depreciated which I found later.
What is the latest way to handle this?

Comment: Deprecated as in it doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You made typo on line 2:

```
const dbMessage = req.body;
```

Another typo on line 3:

```
Messages.create(dbMessage,(err,data) => {
```

Comment: Actually it is correctly typed in the actual code, I think ".create" is depreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer

```
app.post("/message/new", (req, res) => {
  const message = req.body.message;
  const newMessage = new Message({
    "message": message,
  });
  newMessage.save();
  res.status(200).json(newMessage);
});
```